# count duplicate entries within each column

Tags: text-processing, awk, text-formatting

My file contains a hundred of columns.

I need to:

- first counting duplicates entries within each column
- then display output columns order by the number of rows (max to min).

Input file:

```
a     b     c     d     e
11    11    22    56    11
11    44    56    89    11
12    56    78    91    11 
22    60    78          11
22    60    91
      60    98
      91
      91
      95
```

Output file:

```
b       c       a       d       e
11      22      11(2)   56      11(4)
44      56      12      89
56      78(2)   22(2)   91
60(3)   91
91(2)   98
95
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk fo arrays of arrays and `sorted_in`:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR == 1 {
    numCols = split($0,tags)
    next
}
{
    for ( colNr=1; colNr<=NF; colNr++ ) {
        val = $colNr
        if ( val != "" ) {
            if ( !seen[colNr][val]++ ) {
                ++colRowNrs[colNr]
            }
            rowNr = colRowNrs[colNr]
            numRows = ( rowNr > numRows ? rowNr : numRows )
            rowColVals[rowNr][colNr] = val
            rowColCnts[rowNr][colNr]++
        }
    }
}
END {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
    for ( colNr in colRowNrs ) {
        tag = tags[colNr]
        printf "%s%s", tag, (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
    }
    for ( rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++ ) {
        for ( colNr in colRowNrs ) {
            val = rowColVals[rowNr][colNr]
            cnt = rowColCnts[rowNr][colNr]
            printf "%s%s%s", val, (cnt > 1 ? "("cnt")" : ""), (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
b       c       a       d       e
11      22      11(2)   56      11(4)
44      56      12      89
56      78(2)   22(2)   91
60(3)   91
91(2)   98
95
```

The above assumes your input is tab-separated - if that's wrong then edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for the [*`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) and knowing that columns are delimited with a single Space or Tab character which otherwise the position of each field in every lines will be vary; one input something as following (fields are enclosed within brackets for better view and number of fields in every line are the same but some fields are empty):

```
[a]   [b]   [c]   [d]   [e]
[11]  [11]  [22]  [56]  [11]
[11]  [44]  [56]  [89]  [11]
[12]  [56]  [78]  [91]  [11]
[22]  [60]  [78]  []    [11]
[22]  [60]  [91]  []    []
[]    [60]  [98]  []    []
[]    [91]  []    []    []
[]    [91]  []    []    []
[]    [95]  []    []    []
```

Here I assumed that delimiter is a single Tab character; if it's Space character just replace `\t` with Space in *`-F'[\t]' -v OFS='\t'` -> `-F'[ ]' -v OFS=' '`*.

```c
gawk -F'[\t]' -v OFS='\t' '
function prnt(){
    for(e=1;e<=NF;e++) printf "%s", buf[e] (e==NF?ORS:OFS); split("", buf)
};
NR==1{ split($0, hdr) }
NR >1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i!=""&& count[$i"," i]++ }

END  { for(k in count) { split(k, tmp, ","); uniq[tmp[2]]++ }
       PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"
       for(u in uniq) {
           if(!ent)ent=uniq[u]*(NF+1);
           printf "%s" ,(s?OFS:"") hdr[u]; ordr[++s]=u
       }; print ""

       PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";
       while(v++<=ent){
           if(j++==NF){ j=0; prnt() }
           for(k in count){
               split(k, tmp, ",")
               if(tmp[2]==ordr[j]){
                   buf[j]=tmp[1] (count[k]>1?"("count[k]")":"")
                   delete count[k]; break
               };
           };
       };
}' infile
```

Output:

```
b       c       a       d       e
11      22      11(2)   56      11(4)
44      56      12      89
56      78(2)   22(2)   91
60(3)   91
91(2)   98
95
```

Enclosing within brackets:

```
b       c       a       d       e
[11]    [22]    [11(2)] [56]    [11(4)]
[44]    [56]    [12]    [89]    []
[56]    [78(2)] [22(2)] [91]    []
[60(3)] [91]    []      []      []
[91(2)] [98]    []      []      []
[95]    []      []      []      []
```

- `NR==1{ split($0, hdr) }`, if it's first line (`NR==1`, **N**umber of **R**ecord), then [split()](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) it into the pieces and store in the *hdr* array.
- `NR >1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i!=""&& count[$i"," i]++ }`, for any line other that the first line (`NR>1`) we loop over the fields (or columns; `NF` return the **N**umber of **F**ields in a line) and if the current processing field was not empty string (`$i!=""`), then add that field into the array *count* and increment that field repeated times within that column#; In the `count[i"," $i]++` array, we used combination of the columnValue+column# as the ***key*** of the array *count* separated with a comma and ***values*** are the occurrences of each entries that seen in the same column#;
- In the `END{ ... }` we are doing several things:

  - `for(k in count) { split(k, tmp, ","); uniq[tmp[2]]++ }`, here we loop over the *count* array's ***key's elemnts*** and split() that *key* (`k`) into a new temporary array *tmp* on comma separator (we said above that *"we used combination of the column#+columnValue as the ***key*** of the array *count* separated with a comma"*) and get the second part (i.e, column# part) and then we are now counting the occurrences of those column#s to see how many unique entries were there within each column# (`uniq[tmp[2]]++`); we need this calculation to sort the output based on the columns having the maximum entries at first unto minimum entries in last; now column# are the keys part of the array *uniq* and values are the unique entries in each column.
  - `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"`, this enables the GNU awk array sorting options when they traversed in the loops and we used sort on **val**ues **num**erical **desc**ending which will sort the array's values descending.
  - `for(u in uniq) { ... }`, loop over the array *uniq* which is created earlier.

    - `if(!ent)ent=uniq[u]*(NF+1);`, you remember that above we sorted the array *uniq* on values, so the first element would be the column# with highest unique entries in it; we build *`ent`* variable with the maximum entries in that column multiply NF+1 to remember the 2D dimensions of the input file which we will rebuild output file based on this.
    - `printf "%s" ,(s?OFS:"") hdr[u];` print header elements from column# with max entries to column# with min entries (array was sorted on values, so the column with highest entries now is first and so accordingly it's key in `u` is also would seen at first and when we do printing the `hdr[u]` it will print headers by that order max->min)
    - `ordr[++s]=u`, with this we wanted to remember which column# (keys are coming from the `u` from the array *uniq*) should print first, so we created a new temporary array *ordr* with keys as like `1,2,3,5,5, etc` incremental and values are the column# which they should print at first;
  - `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";`, here we changed the sorting method to **ind**xes **num**erical **asc**ending which will sort the array's on index/keys part.
  - `while(v++<=ent){ ... }`, we are doing several things by opening a loop and run it until `v<ent` (until we traversed all cells of a 2D dimension matrix; in this example ent=6*6=36);

    - `if(j++==NF){ j=0; prnt() }`, if control variable `j==NF` then it means we traversed a full line with NF number of fields, so reset it `j=0` and call `prnt()` function to output the line and process the next line of the code below;
    - `for(k in count){ ... }`, loop over the array *count* which is contains the entries and thier column position.

      - `split(k, tmp, ",")`, split() the *key* (`k`) part into the temporary array *tmp* on comma separator.
      - `if(tmp[2]==ordr[j])`, if the second part of the key (i.e, column# part) was equal to the order from the `ordr[#]` array?

        - `buf[j]=tmp[1] (count[k]>1?"("count[k]")":"")`, build the field by printing the first part of the key from the `tmp[1]` (which is columnValue+...) then print the occurrences times from the `count[k]` (you omitted to print the repeats for unique entries so we also skipping those entries too and printing if it `count[k]>1`)
        - `delete count[k]; break`, delete that key which is processed and break from inner first loop and run outer loop;
    - otherwise test another entries
  - jump to while-loop and process all other entries
- end
- `function prnt(){ ... }`, output the line after rebuild and and empty the *buf* array for the next processing.

Answer (score 0):

One way using the linux utilities is shown here.

```
if="$PWD/file"
tmp=$(mktemp -d) || exit
cd -- "$tmp"

nf=$(awk -F '\t' '{print NF;exit}' "$if")

printf -v fmt '%%0%dd\n' "$(expr "$nf" : '.*')"

for i in $(seq "$nf"); do
  cut -f"$i" "$if" | 
  grep -E '[^[:space:]]' |
  uniq -c | awk '{$0 = $2 \
   ($1>1 ? "("$1")" : "")}1' \
  > "$(printf "$fmt" "$i")"
done

wc -l * | sed 's/^\s*//;$d' |
sort -k1,1nr -k2 |
 cut -d" " -f2 |
 sed -e '${y/\n/\t/;q;}' -e 'N;H;z;x;D' |
xargs -l  paste | column-t
```

Output:

```
b      c      a      d   e
11     22     11(2)  56  11(4)
44     56     12     89  
56     78(2)  22(2)  91  
60(3)  91                
91(2)  98                
95
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use perl data structures to solve this problem.

```
perl -F'/\t/,$_,-1'  -lane '
  $.==1 && do{
    @hdr = @F; next;
  };
  for (0..$#F) {
    my $e = $F[$_];
    next if $e eq "";
    my $main_key = $hdr[$_];
    $h{$main_key}{$e}++;
  }
  }{
  my @AoA =
  map {
    my $key = $hdr[$_];
    my $href = $h{$key};
    local($a,$b);
    [
      $key,
      map {
        my $k = $href->{$_};
        $k > 1 ? qq[$_($k)] : $_;
      }
      sort {
        $a <=> $b
      }
      keys %$href
    ]
  }
  sort {
    keys %{$h{$hdr[$b]}} <=> 
    keys %{$h{$hdr[$a]}} ||
    $a <=> $b
  }
  0..$#hdr;

  # output
  local $, = "\t";
  for (my $i=0; $AoA[0][$i] ne ""; $i++) {
    print map($AoA[$_][$i],0..$#AoA)
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
b      c      a      d   e
11     22     11(2)  56  11(4)
44     56     12     89  
56     78(2)  22(2)  91  
60(3)  91                
91(2)  98                
95
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes easier if you transpose your table so columns become lines. You could do that with BSD `rs` for instance:

```
< yourfile unexpand -t6 | # convert to tsv assumming 6-column wide columns
  rs -nTc | # transpose
  gawk -v OFS='\t' '{
    c=0
    for (i=j=2;++j<=NF+1;)
      if ($i == $j"")
        c++
      else{
        if (c++) $i=$i"("c")"
        $++i=$j
        c=0
      }
    print NF=--i,$0
  }' |
  sort -rn |
  cut -f2- |
  rs -nTc
```

Comment: if you change `-vOFS` to `-v OFS`, i.e. with a space between, then that part will work in any awk but if `print NF=--i` is trying to reduce the value of `NF` to strip trailing fields (sorry, I can't tell what the code is doing and I don't have `unexpand` or `rs` on my system to test with, so I'm just guessing based on the `--i`), then that's undefined behavior so some awks will do that while others will ignore it.

Comment: @Ed I've changed to gawk for now. I'll make it more portable when I have a moment

Answer (score 0):

We can use `python`, with the `zip_longest` method from the `itertools` module to interleave the columnar lists.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
fs,rs = "\t","\n"
ofs,ors = fs,rs
t = ()
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for nr,rec in enumerate(f):
    F = rec.rstrip(rs).split(fs)
    if not nr:
      LoL = [[e] for e in F]
    else:
      for idx,el in enumerate(F):
        if el == "": continue
        if not len(t):
          LoL[idx].append(el)
          t = el,
        else:
          p = LoL[idx]
          t = p[-1].replace("(",")").split(")")
          if t[0] == el:
            p[-1] = "%s(%d)" % (el,(int(t[1])+1 if len(t) > 1 else 2))
          else: p.append(el)

  # output
  for tup in it.zip_longest(*sorted(LoL,reverse=True,key=len),fillvalue=""):
    print(*tup,sep=ofs)
' file
```

---

Output:

```
b      c      a      d   e
11     22     11(2)  56  11(4)
44     56     12     89  
56     78(2)  22(2)  91  
60(3)  91                
91(2)  98                
95
```

---

The above assumes that the elements in each column don't come repeated later on down in that column.

Should this scenario not hold, we could use the following approach which combines the ordering of list, uniquifying nature of a set, and the list method count that enumerates how many times a given element was present in the input list.

```
python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it

fs,rs = "\t","\n"
ofs = fs

with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
  for nr,_ in enumerate(f):
    F = _.rstrip(rs).split(fs)
    if not nr:
      LoL = [[e] for e in F]
    else:
      for i,e in enumerate(F):
        if len(e): LoL[i] += [e]

  for idx in range(len(LoL)):
    s = set(LoL[idx])
    l = []
    for el in LoL[idx]:
      if el in s:
        s -= {el}
        k = LoL[idx].count(el)
        if k > 1: el += f"({k})"
        l += [el]
    LoL[idx] = l

  for t in it.zip_longest(*sorted(LoL,key=len,reverse=True),fillvalue=""):
    print(*t,sep=ofs)
' file
```